# How to add drop down suggestions to a text box in Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, input, drop-down-menu, textbox

I have a requirement of combining text-box and drop-down list in Angularjs. 
User should be able to select an item in the drop down list or can enter his own new item and submit the form. I tried ui-select, in which item should be selected from the drop-down list only. User will not able to enter new value.
Any help?

Comment: maybe you can use http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead

Comment: what you are looking at is typeahead

Comment: yes. It is typeahead. My basic requirement is that user should be able to select an item in the drop down list or can enter his own new item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for something simple and lean, just use a filter works quite well in compact arrays